# remove duplicate records syntax error in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

i try to remove duplicate records from table

my sql query is :

```
 DELETE FROM products_description AS t1 WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 'products_id', 'site_language_id'
FROM products_description AS t2
WHERE t2.products_id = t1.products_id
AND t2.site_language_id = t1.site_language_id
);
```

it give this error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t1
where  exists (select 'products_id','site_language_id' from products_desc' at line 1
```

i don't know what is missing ?

Comment: Use back ticks for column names,quotes are for strings and you dont need the alias.

Comment: I think your query will drop all records and not only duplicated

Comment: why the downvote? This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me....

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is complaining since there is a syntax error. Try replacing the quote (') with a backtick (`).

Be careful though! The query will then work but will delete all rows rather than just duplicates....

Comment: slight problem is that tis will delete all rows

Comment: True true. My answer only addresses the quote syntax error. Not the fact the the query is basically flawed. Check out the answer from m hasan....

Comment: Err. Yeah. I agree with you. Hence why I wrote "My answer only addresses the quote syntax error. Not the fact the the query is basically flawed." Anyway. Changed my answer to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all records which have duplicates

```
DELETE FROM products_description
WHERE product_id IN (
                     SELECT product_id FROM( Select product_id,site_language_id
                                             From products_description 
                                             Group By product_id,site_language_id
                                             Having Count(*)>1
                                           ) As X
                    )As Y
```